# cross referencing records across tables

Tags: mysql, database

i have 10 similar tables in my database. all the tables have the same field email in them. i want to find out email addresses that occur in more than 3 tables. the field email is not a primary key.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have the same field or set of fields in 10 tables, you might want to reconsider your database design. It smells like a lack of normalization, which will make queries difficult.

Comment: the database needs to be normalized. its just a temporary one and i need a quick fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `count` function over a `union all` query:

```
SELECT   email, COUNT(*) AS num_tables
FROM     (SELECT DISTINCT email FROM table1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT DISTINCT email FROM table2
          UNION ALL
          -- All the other tables
         ) t
GROUP BY email
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
```